# question about localhost:8080

Tags: web-server

i am writing  projects in GWT    let see site

```
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/buildui.html
```

and when i run project it connects `localhost:8080`  (i have installed appache,PHP  ,mySQL,all works) and does not show me output can anybody help me how mixed this bug?
thanks very much

here is what  it says when i visit localhost:8080

```
Your server is now running

To replace this page, overwrite the file index.html in the document root folder of this server. The document root folder for this server is the docroot subdirectory of this server's domain directory.

To manage a server on the local host with the default administration port, go to the Administration Console.

Register GlassFish Server now

Use the Administration Console to register GlassFish Server now. Registration is optional, but as a registered user you receive benefits such as:

Patch information and bug updates
Screencasts and tutorials
News and events
Support and training offerings
Get Oracle GlassFish Server with Premier Support

For production deployments, consider Oracle GlassFish Server with Oracle Premier Support for Software. Premier Support helps lower the total cost and risk of owning your Oracle solutions, improve the return from your IT investment, and optimize the business value of your IT solutions. Benefits of Premier Support include product updates and enhancements, global reach, lifetime support, ecosystem support, and proactive, automated support.

Install and update additional software components

Use the Update Tool to install and update additional technologies and frameworks such as:

Hibernate JPA
JRuby runtime
Jython container
If you are using the web profile, you can also use Update Tool to obtain technologies that are included by default in the full platform, such as:

Enterprise Java Beans
Metro
Jersey
To improve the user experience and optimize offerings to users, Sun collects data about GlassFish Server usage that is transmitted by the Update Tool installer as part of the automatic update processes. No personally identifiable information is collected by this process.

Join the GlassFish community

Visit the GlassFish Community page for information about how to join the GlassFish community. The GlassFish community is developing an open source, production-quality, enterprise-class application server that implements the newest features of the Java™ Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) platform and related enterprise technologies.

Learn more about GlassFish Server

For more information about GlassFish Server, samples, documentation, and additional resources, see as-install/docs/about.html, where as-install is the GlassFish Server installation directory
```

apaches error_log file

```
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2.2 Service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2.2 Service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2.2 Service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2.2 Service
Starting the Apache2.2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2.2: Failed to open the service.
Starting the Apache2.2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2.2: Failed to open the service.
Starting the Apache2.2 service
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Apache2.2: Failed to open the service.
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:48 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:48 2010] [notice] Server built: Jul 30 2010 16:15:37
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:49 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5924
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:49 2010] [notice] Child 5924: Child process is running
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:49 2010] [notice] Child 5924: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:49 2010] [notice] Child 5924: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:49 2010] [notice] Child 5924: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Aug 11 23:33:55 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 09:18:59 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 09:32:14 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:33:02 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:33:02 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 09:33:21 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:33:21 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 09:34:05 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 09:36:19 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:36:19 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 09:36:58 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:36:58 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:38:48 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 09:38:48 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 10:00:50 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 10:00:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 10:01:14 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 10:01:14 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
(OS 5)Access is denied.  : Failed to open the Apache2.2 Service
[Thu Aug 12 10:01:35 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/phpinfo.php
[Thu Aug 12 10:01:35 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Apache/htdocs/favicon.ico
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [warn] pid file C:/Apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Server built: Jul 30 2010 16:15:37
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 396
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Child 396: Child process is running
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Child 396: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Child 396: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Aug 12 10:05:11 2010] [notice] Child 396: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Aug 12 10:08:24 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/websites/favicon.ico
[Thu Aug 12 10:57:15 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/websites/favicon.ico
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [warn] pid file C:/Apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Server built: Jul 30 2010 16:15:37
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 400
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Child 400: Child process is running
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Child 400: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Child 400: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Aug 12 12:04:31 2010] [notice] Child 400: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:11 2010] [warn] pid file C:/Apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Server built: Jul 30 2010 16:15:37
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 452
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.100 for ServerName
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Child 452: Child process is running
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Child 452: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Child 452: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Aug 12 18:34:12 2010] [notice] Child 452: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: And what does it say exactly when you point browser to http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: looks like it is using glassfish itself instead of apache

Comment: and what to do?

Comment: There's a lot of words there but very little useful information. Please describe your setup and what you think you should be seeing.

Answer (score 1):

have you successfully completed step [one](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html#test) of the tutorial?

it is talking about port 8888 and jetty and not port 8080 and glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

I see "localhost" so I presume you're testing locally (I don't know GWT)
On SSH, try : netstat -tupan 
to get the list of listening ports and the associated program name
And try to read the end of Apache's error_log to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well your Glassfish server seems to be working just fine. Navigating to `http://localhost:8080` simply displays the server's welcome page, so now you need to deploy your GWT application and navigate to it in your browser.

I've only used Tomcat for this, so I'm not sure how Glassfish works exactly. In Tomcat I can simply copy my .war file into a webapps directory and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/<ProjectName>/<MainPage>.html`.

[This Glassfish tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/geyvr/index.html) may help you get started.